# I'm getting an error in plt.imshow while classifying with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to do a classification with tensorflow. I'm getting this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bphDI.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The last line of the error says that you have 28 images. However, you are trying to get 30 images with the line: for n in range(30).

Answer (score 0):

By using the below code will not produce the error

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,9))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
for n in range(30):
  plt.subplot(5,6,1+n)
  plt.imshow(test_images[n])
  if np.argmax(predictions[n]) == test_labels[n]:
    plt.title(class_names[np.argmax(predictions[n])],color='green')
  else:
    plt.title(class_names[np.argmax(predictions[n])],color='red')
```

Output of above code:

[image]

Here i have used test_images, by replacing test_images with the validation images will suit your requirement.

For more details please refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/b8acd6befecd8ed21129eb2ef4f56660).